# 405 Method not allowed - ajax request with laravel route

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel-4

Calling an ajax function should be done this way and I have done it multiple times.This time I keep getting `405 method not allowed`.I know this issue is known but I have tried suggested solutions and still nothing works.
Here's my controller:

```
public function playGame($custom_url)
    {
        $project = Project::where('custom_url', $custom_url)->where('approved', 1)->first();
        if(Request::isMethod('post'))
        {
            $project->play_count = $project->play_count+1;
            $project->save();
            return json_encode(array('status'=>array('saved')));
        }
        return View::make('game.index');
    }
```

index.blade.php:

```
<title>Tennra</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.png"/>

        <link href="{{URL::asset('game/style.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type='text/css'>
        <link href="{{URL::asset('game/menu.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type='text/css'>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{URL::asset('game/jq.js')}}"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{URL::asset('game/mainMenu.js')}}"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{URL::asset('game/game.js')}}"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{URL::asset('game/main.js')}}"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

    </body>
```

games.js:

```
function startedGame() {
    /*********************************
    **********************************
    ***   Add Code Here if Needed  ***
    **********************************
    *********************************/

    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        data: null,
        url: "{{URL::route('projects.game')}}"
      }).done(function( msg )
      {
        msg=JSON.parse(msg);
        if(msg['errors'])
        {
        }
        else if(msg['status'])
        {
            console.log(true);
        }
      });
}
```

Comment: does the same happen if you test it out the POST with Postman (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en)

Comment: @bitoiu works perfectly witth postman but still gives error when tried in the project

Comment: in the chrome dev tools network tab, do you see the request going out? How does it differ with the Postman request? Assuming that 405 is a service error (f'ed up if it's the client), compare the two requests and you should be able to pinpoint what the framework on the client side is doing wrong.

Comment: Post your routes.php as well.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. When I create ajax requests in blade file url is always in this form:

```
url: "{{URL::route('urlname')}}"
```

But since the request was in .js file, the syntax was no longer correct so I had to update it as follows:

```
url: window.location
```

As the post request had the same url as the current window.